# What is the time in the afternoon problem

Tags: arithmetic, problem-solving

I have been reading Ray's Intellectual Arithmetic and I stumbled upon the following problem:

> What is the time in the afternoon, when the time past noon is equal to $1/5$ of 
>   the time past midnight?

The solution goes like this:

> Let $5/5$ be the whole time. The time past noon is $1/5$. From midnight to noon is $4/5$. Then $4/5 = 12$. Therefore $1/5$ is $3$ o'clock in the afternoon.

But $4$ o'clock is also $1/5$ of some time after midnight. Is this problem ambiguous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret the question as currently the time is $x$.

Noon is the time corresponding to $12:00$ hours and midnight is the time corresponding to $00:00$ hours

The time past noon is $x-12$ and the time past midnight is $x-0$.

$$x-12 = \frac15 ( x-0)$$

$$\frac{4x}5=12$$

$$x=15$$

That is $x$ is $15:00$ hours, which corresponds to $3pm$.

Remark about $4$ O' clock is some times after midnight. Let that time be $

$$16-12=\frac15(16-y)$$

$$y=-4$$

There is no time after midnight that make the equation holds unless you are measuring from $8pm$ the previous day.

Comment: But $4pm + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 8am$. Therefore $4pm$ is $1/5$ of $8am$ which is after midnight.

Comment: I am just saying that the question might not be stated clearly. Because when you say $x - 12$ you are assuming that the solution will be the same time before and after midnight, but there are clearly more solutions than that.

Comment: well... usually we can compare the length of time interval. but I am not familiar of comparison of $1pm$ is how many times of $3am$.

Comment: Can you tell me why have you put time past midnight as $x - 0$ and not simply $x$? Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: I'm just highlighting that it's the time interval and midnight is time $0$, of course $x-0=x$.